# Is it possible to compile only mixins in scss?

Tags: sass

I have a scss file with some partial mixins. I want to compile only that mixin, without converting it to CSS. Let me show you the code.

```
@mixin baseButton() {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

  &:disabled {
    background-color: gray;
  }
}

@mixin button($classname:".midori-button") {
  #{$classname} {
    color: gray;
    @include baseButton();
  }
}

@include button();
```

Is it possible compile this code into SCSS like the above but not into CSS like:

```
.midori-button {
  color: gray;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

  &:disabled {
    background-color: gray;
  }
}
```

Thanks.

P.S: Not native.

Comment: Valid question, but why are you attempting to do this?

Comment: trying to write adapters for different build targets like css modules or bem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm reading this question right but you can create mixin partials that does not render CSS by adding an underscore to the file name like _button.scss

If you do that you should place the @inclue in the file/files you want to render CSS (using @import to make the mixins available).

```
// _button.scss => No CSS
@mixin baseButton(){ ... }
@mixin button(){ ...}


// module-1.scss  => module-1.css
@import '_button.scss';
@include baseButton;
@include button;

// module-2.scss  => module-2.css 
@import '_button.scss';
@include baseButton;
@include button;
```